# Onclick not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to get an  element to both follow it's link (which downloads a file) and then be redirected to a new page. For some reason the element downloads the file but the onclick function is never executed. I've tried a couple different implementations... Here's what I've done so far:

```
$("#download").onclick = function() {window.location.assign('www.redirect.com')};
```

I've also tried all of these with console logs in them which also never get executed.

```
function safari_click() {
    window.location.assign("www.redirect.com");
}

$("#download").onclick = safari_click;

//finally also this one:

$("#download").onclick = function() {safari_click()};
```

I can't get any of these to actually trigger the onclick function.

Edit: Also, just to be clear the #download element is a link which also has href defined. Not sure if this is messing it up somehow.

Comment: By using jQuery, you should use their native `.click(function())` or `.on('click', function() { })` instead of assigning a handler via the  `.onclick` property.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, please [**read the tutorial** about event handling first](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/). This is not the correct way of binding an event handler to a jQuery object (DOM elements have an `onclick` property, jQuery objects don't). The tutorial explains how to do that.

Comment: could you please mention the html code or (dom). i think you are not using #download as id

Comment: Read the documentation before asking questions http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are getting jQuery's API a little mixed up.

Try this:

```
function safari_click() {
    window.location.href = "www.redirect.com";
}

$("#download").click(safari_click);
```

More information on click() here: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Aha! That worked! Now the console log is getting outputted, but the redirect still isn't firing. Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Comment: A little off-topic from the original question... but: window.location.href = "www.redirect.com";

Answer (score 0):

When you call jquery $ it return a jQuery object, to access onclick of element you need access first element inside jQuery object.

try :

`$("#download")[0].onclick = function() {window.location.assign('www.redirect.com')};`

you can use :

`$("#download).click(function() { window.location.assign('www.redirect.com'); });`